# Extracting data from Wikipedia table (titles of episodes)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table, wikipedia

I'm trying to extract the titles of TV episodes from Wikipedia's tables, using BeautifulSoup and Python.
For explaining what I;ve done so far, I'm using two tables:

1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_(season_1)

2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_and_a_Half_Men_(season_1)

Now, in the tables, each episode is contained in a `<td class="summary">`.
In the first table, the `<td>` also has an `<a>`TitleName`</a>`, and I'm able to extract the data with the following code quite well:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_(season_1)"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for names in soup.select('td[class="summary"] > a'):
    print names.string
```

But the problem arises in the second table, i.e. Two and a Half Men, where the titles are inside `<td>`
I use this code to extract them:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_and_a_Half_Men_(season_1)"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for lel in soup.select('td[class="summary"]'):
    print lel.string
```

But the tiles come with quotes, i.e. "".
I'm guessing that removing the quotes would be easy, but what if in one table, some `<td>`'s contain `<a>` and some don't? How can I let python decide whether or not it should check for an `<a>` element?

If in the first code block, i remove `> a` , then I get none as the output, because parent and child both contain strings. If i then proceed to use `names.strings` I get

`<generator object _all_strings at 0x01B1CDA0>`

If I use `soup.get_text()` I get 
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 6818, character maps to <undefined>`

Please Help :)

Comment: Another suggestion: instead of parsing Wikipedia pages, parse the xml from TVRage: http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/full_show_info.php?sid=22589 for Community and http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/full_show_info.php?sid=6454 for 2½ Men

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `.text`?

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_and_a_Half_Men_(season_1)"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for lel in soup.select('td[class="summary"]'):
    print lel.text.replace('"','') # remove the quote marks as well
```

This will print all the names without the quotes and it fixes the `None` problem.

```
Pilot
Most Chicks Won't Eat Veal
Big Flappy Bastards
etc...
```

Comment: Wow it works great! Thanks for the quick response, I wasn't aware of the text method, guess I need to learn BeautifulSoup a bit more!

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of trying the tvrage API ?

```
import tvrage.api
community = tvrage.api.Show('Community')
twohalfmen = tvrage.api.Show('Two and a Half Men')
comeps = community.season(1).episode(1)
twoeps = twohalfmen.season(1).episode(2)
>>> comeps
Community 1x01 Pilot
>>> twoeps
Two and a Half Men 1x02 Big Flappy Bastards
>>> community.season(1)
{1: Community 1x01 Pilot, 2: Community 1x02 Spanish 101, 3: Community 1x03 Introduction to Film,
4: Community 1x04 Social Psychology, 5: Community 1x05 Advanced Criminal Law, 6: Community 1x06 Football, Feminism and You,
7: Community 1x07 Introduction to Statistics, 8: Community 1x08 Home Economics, 9: Community 1x09 Debate 109, 10: Community 1x10 Environmental Science,
11: Community 1x11 The Politics of Human Sexuality, 12: Community 1x12 Comparative Religion, 13: Community 1x13 Investigative Journalism, 14: Community 1x14 Interpretive Dance, 15: Community 1x15 Romantic Expressionism, 16: Community 1x16 Communication Studies, 17: Community 1x17 Physical Education, 18: Community 1x18 Basic Genealogy, 19: Community 1x19 Beginner Pottery, 20: Community 1x20 The Science of Illusion, 21: Community 1x21 Contemporary American Poultry, 22: Community 1x22 The Art of Discourse, 23: Community 1x23 Modern Warfare, 24: Community 1x24 English as a Second Language, 25: Community 1x25 Pascal's Triangle Revisited}
```

Comment: Your answer is also quite good, and in fact a better way for what I'm doing, but chose the other one as accepted as I can now use BeautifulSoup for other stuff as well...